# Android: Don't exit after an exception

Tags: android, exception, authentication, dialog, httpclient

How can i make that my app dosen't exit after an UnknownHostException?

My code actually:

```
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url, String Username, String Passwd){
    String xml = null;
    try{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());

        NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials(Username, Passwd, "AndroidApp", "****");

        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 1000);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("HTTPClient", "Unknown Host");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("HTTPClient", "Connection Timeout");
    } catch (NoHttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("HTTPClient", "No Response");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }

    return xml;
}
```

To get the exception is to click on a login button then the app load an xml file over http on the phone.
In place of the exception comes an dialog for User that the hostname don't exists.

Same for other exceptions...

**Update:
Ok i've found a solution.
I had added a NullPointerException when i'm switching between the Fragments**

Comment: Please show us how the application exits.  The code you have here will catch the the UnknownHostException and will not exit, because of it.  Are you getting an NPE on the returned value?

Comment: Yes the application exits with an NPE because the 'xml' is empty. I've tried it with: xml = "0"